# How to log input range value when changed programmatically using javascript and alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I've created a simple app to console log input range value when the input range change. When I move the slider left-right with my pointer it works perfectly but when I change the value using javascript, the slider value does change but the console.log won't start so there's no log in the console.

```
// change input range value programmatically with javascript
const slider = document.getElementById('slider')
slider.value=4 // the input range button indicator has moved
```

```
// when change with mouse cursor manually the console.log successfully log the data value
// but when I do it programmatically with Javascript it fails to log the data
<div x-data="{data: 3}">
  <input type="range" id="slider" name="slider" min="1" max="5" x-model="data" @change="console.log(data)">
</div>
```

Comment: you can do console.log(document.getElementbyId('slider').value);

Answer (score 1):

Programatically changing values doesn't trigger an update. If you dispatch an event, it will be caught:

```js
// Set bubbles to true so it can bubble up in the DOM
// Set cancelable to true so the event can be stopped (preventDefault)
let event = new Event('change', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
slider.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: hello Yinci, thank you for the answer, but after I create a dispatch even in on change event at input range and listened for that event, and then change the value from it, it still couldn't be able to make work when changed programmatically

could you please give us more detailed answer about this,